# zend Framework 2 update query by TableGateway Object

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db, tablegateway

```
public function update($table, $where = array(), $data_arr = array()){

    print_r($data_arr);

    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();

    $projectTable;

    if($table != null){
        $projectTable = new TableGateway($table, $adapter);
    }else{
        $projectTable = new TableGateway('account_master', $adapter);
    }
    echo "158";

    try {
        echo "123";
        $rowset = $projectTable->update(function(Update $update) use ($where, $data_arr) {

                $update->set(array('statement_no' => '01010'));

                $update->where($where);

            echo $update->getSqlString();
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r($e);
    }

    print_r($rowset);
    die();
}
```

my Output print : 158123
it's give me pass array in set() function that i already pass as argument. also i have tried to convert object to array ((arrya)$objetc) but it's not work for me.

```
[10-Jul-2017 05:11:34 America/Denver] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Zend\Db\Sql\Update::set() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home2/flywing1/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/TableGateway/AbstractTableGateway.php on line 336 and defined in /home2/flywing1/vendor/zendframework/zend-db/src/Sql/Update.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do that by implementing a `Zend\Db\Sql\Update` object. You may create that object using the `TableGateway`. You should be able to do the following in your model

```
public function update($set, $where)
{
    // Here is the catch  
    $update = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->update();
    $update->set($set);
    $update->where($where);

    // Execute the query
    return $this->tableGateway->updateWith($update);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it,
I was with the same issues, I tried with this, and it worked.

```
$rowset = $projectTable->update(array('statement_no' => '01010'), $where);
```